# sending ajax request contains http string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When sending a form with ajax to php page everything goes ok, until 1 of my fields contains some url string with the prefix http:// .
I getting error (Forbidden) from the ajax request.

This is my js code:

```
$('#ajaxForm').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var form_data = $(this).serializeArray();
  console.log(form_data);

  $.ajax({
      type        : 'POST',
      url         : 'functions/ajax_functions.php',
      dataType  : 'json',
      data        : form_data,
  })
      .done(function(data) {

          console.log(data);
          return;
      })
      .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
});
```

The error appears only when the input value contain "http://...", if any other string is sent - the request is sent successfully.

This is the my console log screenshot:
[image: console log]

**Update:**

- I tried to use the encodeURI and encodeURIComponent functions. I saw in the console that the special characters did changed but it didn't help.
- Also, tried to give all my files the 777 permissions and it didn't help

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds more like a php server restriction problem and not a javascript issue.

Comment: It seems that the PHP server is rejecting the request, the above script seems alright.

Comment: Have you tried encoding the data and then decode it on the other end.

Comment: Seconded. This appears to be a serve-side problem instead of a client-side one.

Comment: Yes, I tried to encoded the string. And the php server not blocking my request if this current input contain some other string...

Comment: This sounds like either you have some application firewall (e.g. mod_security or similar) on your server, or you are behind CloudFlare or similar CDN. You can check this by putting a `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));die;` as a very first line in `ajax_functions.php` - if you get 403 instead of the var_dump then the problem is neither in JavaScript nor in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to IVO GELOV! This is the right answer in my case.**

I have some firewall on my apache server called ModSecurity.
I disable this option on this current subdomain and...... WALLLLLA...

I know that now my subdomain lose the extra layer of protection that the module provides,
but I found the problem and know for sure it's not in my code.

Thanks guys!